# How to build latest Qt from Git repository on windows?

Tags: qt, build-process, building

I have tried to build a latest Qt from the [Git repository](http://qt.gitorious.org/) on Windows with the following commands:

```
mkdir c:\qt\latest
cd c:\qt\latest
git clone git://gitorious.org/qt/qt.git
cd qt
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\qt\latest\qt\bin
configure.exe
```

Unfortunately configuration stops very early with error the following error:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 9.00.30729.01 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl -c -Foproject.obj  -W3 -nologo -O2  -I. -Igenerators -Igenerators\unix -Igenerators\win32 -Igenerators\mac -Igenerators\symbian  -IC:\Qt\latest\qt\include -IC:\Qt\latest\qt\include\QtCore  -IC:\Qt\latest\qt\include -IC:\Qt\latest\qt\include\QtCore  -IC:\Qt\latest\qt\src\corelib\global  -IC:\Qt\latest\qt\src\corelib\xml  -IC:\Qt\latest\qt\mkspecs\win32-msvc2008   -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_LITE_COMPONENT -DQT_NODLL -DQT_NO_STL  -DQT_NO_COMPRESS -DUNICODE -DHAVE_QCONFIG_CPP -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_NO_THREAD  -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT -DQT_NO_DATASTREAM -DQT_NO_PCRE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED   -DQMAKE_OPENSOURCE_EDITION project.cpp
project.cpp c:\qt\latest\qt\qmake\project.h(45) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'qstringlist.h': No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2' Stop.
Building qmake failed, return code 2
```

I have sucessfully built Qt (with the same commands) from source code archive on [qt.nokia.com](http://qt.nokia.com/).

Is there any difference between the code in the *source code archive* and the *Git repository*? Is the Git repository broken/incomplete, or do I need to use additional or different commands to build it?

Comment: http://knowledges.tumblr.com/post/753240784/how-to-statically-compile-qt-from-git

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have two ideas:

1) Try to build in c:\qt\latest\qt\ subfolder. For example:

```
mkdir qt-build
cd qt-build
..\qt\configure
(n)make
```

2) As mentioned [here](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/pages/GetTheSource) may be you need Perl.

> Make sure that you have Perl installed and that it is working. If configure complains about not being able to find headers. It means that syncqt, a program run by configure could not find your Perl installation.

Try to install [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/) i.e.

Comment: Yep, the problem was with perl. It seems that i missed the prerequisites. Thanks a lot!