# Can't build Qt in Windows from source, Perl installed but still can't find headers

Tags: windows, qt, build, cygwin, configure

I'm using Cygwin on Windows 7, 64-bit.  I downloaded the 4.8.3. source and followed the instructions [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/install-win.html), putting `<qtdir>/bin` in PATH along with the path to my chosen compiler.  Configure fails immediately,

> $ ./configure
>
> Creating qmake. Please
>   wait... g++ -c -o makefile.o -pipe -DQMAKE_OPENSOURCE_EDITION -g -I.
>   -Igenerators -Igenerators/unix -Igenerators/win32 -Igenerators/mac -Igenerators/symbian -Igenerators/integrity -I/cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.3/include -I/cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.3/include/QtCore -I/cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.3/src/corelib/global -I/cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.3/src/corelib/xml -I/cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.3/tools/shared -DQT_NO_PCRE -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DQLIBRARYINFO_EPOCROOT -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_COMPONENT -DQT_NO_STL -DQT_NO_COMPRESS -I/cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.3/mkspecs/cygwin-g++ -DHAVE_QCONFIG_CPP -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT -DQT_NO_DEPRECATED  generators/makefile.cpp
>
> In file included from ./option.h:45:0,
>                    from generators/makefile.h:45,
>                    from generators/makefile.cpp:42: ./project.h:45:25: fatal error: qstringlist.h: No such file or directory compilation
>   terminated. make: *** [makefile.o] Error 1

Discussions [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/5360) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084766/how-to-build-latest-qt-from-git-repository-on-windows) identify the problem as being with Perl; however Perl is on my system and on the path.  To be sure I went and downloaded/installed ActivePerl, after which I added `Perl64/bin` to the path.  Same result.  Would very much appreciate some help out with this.

**Edit**, for completeness:

> $ whereis perl
>
> perl: /bin/perl.exe /usr/bin/perl.exe /usr/share/perl
>   /cygdrive/c/Perl64/bin/perl.exe /cygdrive/c/Perl64/bin/perl516.dll
>
> $ echo $PATH
>
> /cygdrive/c/Perl64/bin:/cygdrive/c/gcc/bin:/bin: ...
>   /cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.3/bin

**Edit**: The line that fails is:

```
#include <qstringlist.h>
```

This specific error goes away if I replace with an absolute path.  (Of course, numerous other errors then arise.) Yet

> $whereis qstringlist.h
>
> qstringlist:
>   /cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.3/include/QtCore/qstringlist.h

which is explicitly `-I` included in the g++ command, and FWIW

> ```
> $echo $PATH
>
> ... /cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.3/include/QtCore
> ```

**Edit:** Adding `-I/cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.3/include/QtCore` as an explicit option to `./configure` does nothing.  Seriously, what is going on here...

**Update**: This question is now effectively worth 250 rep., see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277856/how-to-build-gsl-with-msvc2010).

Comment: to me the problem seems to be that the compiler is set to  cygwin-g++ and it complains that it doesn't know how to create projects for this type of compiler

Comment: @MihaiSebea Indeed I am trying to compile under cygwin-g++ but could you explain more where you think the problem is arising for it?  cygwin-g++ is included in Qt's `mkspecs` directory.  Moreover it happens whether I include `-platform cygwin-g++` or not, I would have expected `mingw` to be the default.

Comment: Phillis As far as i can tell cygwin is supported only under linux .. http://lists.qt.nokia.com/pipermail/qt-interest/2009-September/012377.html since on windows there is a different folder structure that is not supported .

Comment: @MihaiSebea http://www.cygwin.com/ Cygwin is a Windows program.

Answer (score 1):

Please, take a look to [supported platforms](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/supported-platforms.html), there you have instructions on supported compilers, which could give you hints on your problem.

As far as i read, in recent windows you need MSVC, and I don't see anything about cygwin.

Comment: I hadn't seen this, that's pretty interesting.  However, ultimately you should be able to build Qt from source from any compiler no?  So the fact that they haven't specifically tested it for g++ doesn't mean you shouldn't be able to do it.  In the installation instructions they specifically discuss how you can pick alternate platforms.  That you can't get g++ to see the path that qstringlist.h is on is pretty hard to believe.

Comment: BTW, Have you used just plain ./configure or have you used any modifiers? Check: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/configure-options.html and http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/install-win.html. For example: configure -platform win32-g++

Comment: Yes I supply the cygwin-g++ or win32-g++ arguments for the `-platform` option and get the above result.  `./configure` probably defaults to one of these.

Comment: and ./configure.exe? Here someone said it helped him :http://osdir.com/ml/MinGW-users/2012-04/msg00092.html

Comment: And I would recommend taking a look to http://cygwinports.org/, they seem to have patches to compile QT. http://cygwin-ports.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=cygwin-ports/qt4;a=summary

Comment: Ok I'm away from my machine right now but I will look into all of these.

Comment: @kikeenrique 9 years later, just wanted to say thank you. After struggling with this issue for ~a week and not finding answers anywhere, tracking down configure.exe and using that instead of the script finally helped. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact configure lines you are using?  Try this:

```
./configure -I/cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.3/include/
```

If it is still complaining about not being able to find the headers, then that is bizarre indeed.  Another option you can try is:

```
INCLUDE_PATH=/cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.3/include/ ./configure
```